# How to restore /bin/sh

Tags: bash, password, restore

Sup yall,

I was trying to fix GUI login or restore password issue on Raspberry Pi 4. There are so many topics and several solutions to solve a problem where you're stuck into a loop asking for a password before entering in the desktop mode. So, I did by accident `sudo rm /bin/sh`. Therefore, I deleted everything on /bin/sh. But it seems to be necessary to run install/remove commands. Even forcing reinstall tells me the following error:

> E: sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (100)
> E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-lischanges --apt || test $? -lt 10

or

> Can't exec "/bin/sh": No such a file or directory at ...

Is there any way to resolve, add or restore /bin/sh files manually?

Greetings,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh

sudo ln -sf dash /bin/sh

these commands helped me to restore the lost files

Comment: Please put a checkmark next to your answer after the waiting period. Then it won't pop up again and again for years after.